# can i create songs with the html5 audio api

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web

Is it possible to create and play songs using the html5 audio/web-audio api's.  If I were to build a miniature audacity type application where you could edit songs and put pieces of them together and then export it as a new song, or at the very least play it.  I've been looking around and I see lots of information on reading song data and manipulating it on the fly, but I have not found anything that would allow you to create one from your own audio data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can be done. [Stuart Memo](http://stuartmemo.com/) has done some awesome work in this area that I would check out as a starting point.  Not sure how you would create and save an audio file.

Hope that helps.